# Getting an error while converting frozen inference graph (*.pb) to tflite graph with toco

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've trained the R-FCN model on my own training set. Now, I'd like to convert my frozen inference graph form the *.pb format to the *.tflite format to use it on an android mobile phone.

After training, i exportet the frozen inference graph with the following command:

```
python3 export_inference_graph.py 
--pipeline_config_path="training/ckpt/rfcn-69/pipeline.config" 
--trained_checkpoint_prefix="training/ckpt/rfcn-69/model.ckpt-300000" 
--output_directory="training/ckpt/rfcn-69/"
```

Afterwards I run the transform_graph util to quantize the graph. I noticed that it doesn't matter wether I run the transform_graph or not. In the end I'm getting the same error with both of the graphs.

```
bazel run tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph -- 
--in_graph="/git/bda/frozen_graphs/rfcn-69/frozen_inference_graph.pb" 
--out_graph="/git/bda/frozen_graphs/rfcn-69/quantized_graph_2.pb" 
--inputs=image_tensor 
--outputs="num_detections,detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes" 
--transforms='fold_old_batch_norms quantize_weights strip_unused_nodes sort_by_execution_order obfuscate_names merge_duplicate_nodes'
```

Finally, I try to convert the quantized graph to an tflite graph with the toco util.

```
bazel run --config=opt  tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco -- 
--input_file=/git/bda/frozen_graphs/rfcn-69/quantized_graph_2.pb 
--output_file=/git/bda/frozen_graphs/out.tflite --inference_type=FLOAT 
--input_shape=1,600,1024,3 
--input_array=image_tensor 
--output_arrays=num_detections,detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes
```

But, the operation fails with the following error.

```
2018-04-11 13:19:58.364591: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1253] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2018-04-11 13:19:58.364606: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1253] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2018-04-11 13:19:58.364656: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1253] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayReadV3
2018-04-11 13:19:58.364753: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1253] Converting unsupported operation: Where
2018-04-11 13:19:58.364851: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1253] Converting unsupported operation: Where
2018-04-11 13:19:58.364969: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1253] Converting unsupported operation: Dequantize
2018-04-11 13:19:58.365001: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1253] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
2018-04-11 13:19:58.365022: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1253] Converting unsupported operation: Dequantize
2018-04-11 13:19:58.366115: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1253] Converting unsupported operation: Where
2018-04-11 13:20:00.620101: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:821] Check failed: d >= 1 (0 vs. 1)
```

I've got no clue what could be the problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind [opening an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new)? I believe this is something we'd like to support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I opened an issue under https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19078